# Xamarin Forms: How to set all labels style in one liner code?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So I have a XF application with multiple `Label`s. I want to be able to change all my label's `FontStyle` programmatically depending on the platform in one line if possible like below instead of listing the label's name one by one.

```
if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android) {
    label.Style = Device.Styles.ListItemDetailTextStyle;
} else if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS){
    label.Style = Device.Styles.ListItemTextStyle;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative option is to simply extend `Label`:

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    public MyLabel()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            Style = Device.Styles.ListItemDetailTextStyle;
        }
        else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            Style = Device.Styles.ListItemTextStyle;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.: Styling is nicely covered in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/).

Answer (score 2):

You should set style in App.xaml file. I needed to set default fonts for all Labels in application (including new classes derived from Label)

```
 <Style ApplyToDerivedTypes="true" TargetType="Label">
  <Style.Triggers>
   <Trigger TargetType="Label" Property="FontAttributes" Value="None">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MainFontFamily}" />
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger TargetType="Label" Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MainFontFamilyBold}" />
   </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
  <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
 </Style>
```

And set fonts like

```
 <OnPlatform x:Key="MainFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
  <On Platform="Android">font_file_name.ttf#Font Name</On>
  <On Platform="iOS">Font Name</On>
 </OnPlatform>
```

You can read more in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/) about styles